# Is there a way to distinguish an undefines is passed explicitly or implicitly?

Tags: javascript

Imagine I have a function looks like this:

```js
const greetings = name => {
   return name === undefined ? 'Hello!' : `Hello, ${name || 'user'}!`;
}
```

There're two ways to call this function:

1. `greetings()`
2. `greetings(user.name)`

For the first use case, because it is called explicitly without an argument, I just want it to output `"Hello"`. Which is working as intended.

For the second use case, if the `user.name` is `"Bob"`, it should output `"Hello, Bob!"`. But if the `user` doesn't have a name (`user.name` is `undefined`). It should fallback to `"user"`: `"Hello, user!"`, but now it outputs `"Hello!"`.

I know I could change the function to `(...args) => {}` or change it to `function greetings() {}` and use `arguments`. But I'm just curious, is there a way to distinguish these two use cases **without changing the function declaration**?

```js
const greetings = name => {
   return name === undefined ? 'Hello!' : `Hello, ${name || 'user'}!`;
}

const user1 = { id: 1, name: 'Bob' };
const user2 = { id: 2 };  // The user hasn't set up completely

console.log(greetings());             // Hello!
console.log(greetings(user1.name));   // Hello, Bob!
console.log(greetings(user2.name));   // Hello, user!
```

Comment: `without changing the function body` No. `undefined` is `undefined`.

Comment: It will never hit the second condition as passing in undefined will be, well, undefined.

Comment: @tkausl I think I made a typo there. By function body, what I meant to say was how the function was declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Without changing function body?" no.

But here is a more elegant way using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
const greetings = user => `Hello${ user ? `, ${user?.name ?? 'user'}` : ''}!`;

const user1 = { id: 1, name: 'Bob' };
const user2 = { id: 2 }; // The user hasn't set up completely

console.log(greetings());      // Hello!
console.log(greetings(user1)); // Hello, Bob!
console.log(greetings(user2)); // Hello, user!
```

Or if you want to keep the greetings function simple

```js
const greetings = (name = '') => `Hello${name}!`;
const getName = user => user ? `, ${user?.name ?? 'user'}` : ''

const user1 = { id: 1, name: 'Bob' };
const user2 = { id: 2 }; // The user hasn't set up completely


console.log(greetings());      // Hello!
console.log(greetings(getName(user1))); // Hello, Bob!
console.log(greetings(getName(user2))); // Hello, user!
```

Comment: So I just need to pass the `user` object itself but not `user.name`. Which syntactically works better in this case.

Comment: I agree. It is possibly better to pass the name, but then the same logic should be somewhere else. See second example

Comment: I think I'll take the first approach since it has no intermediate function created and works well with types.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `null` for this case. For eg:

`console.log(greetings(null));   // Hello, user!`

So, you need to call the `greetings` like `greetings(userName || null)`

```js
const greetings = name => {
   return name === undefined ? 'Hello!' : `Hello, ${name || 'user'}!`;
}

let name;
console.log(greetings(name));       // Hello!
console.log(greetings()); // Hello!
name = 'Bob'; 
console.log(greetings(name)); // Hello, Bob!
name = undefined;
console.log(greetings(name || null));   // Hello, user!
```

Comment: Ah I see, so it just prevents `undefined` gets passed explicitly. Not what I imagined but it works

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to mark it as answer if you like.